# How to use Azure storage for elmah logs instead of elmah logs in SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, elmah.mvc

Currently in my project, I am logging exceptions by using `elmah` in a separate table in SQL Server. Is it possible to store these elmah exceptions in Azure storage only, not in SQL Server? Since I do not want to log errors in my database.

```
//web.config     
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
              connectionStringName="DatabaseConnectionStringName" />
</elmah>
```

Currently in my `web.config`, I configure for elmah logs in SQL Server.

Set allowRemoteAccess = 1 and added errorlog type as `Elmah.SqlErrorLog`. Can 
anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, we can store elmah exceptions in Azure table storage.

We need to use this package: `Elmah.AzureTableStorage`.

We can install this via VS Package Manager:`Install-Package Elmah.AzureTableStorage -Version 1.0.0`.

In web.config, we can set as below:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.AzureTableStorage.AzureTableStorageErrorLog, Elmah.AzureTableStorage"
connectionStringName="ElmahAzureTableStorage" />
```

I have tested and the screenshot of my log in table storage for your reference:

[image]

More information for your reference:

[GitHub: Elmah.AzureTableStorage](https://github.com/MisinformedDNA/Elmah.AzureTableStorage)

[ELMAH on Azure Table Storage](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Elmah.AzureTableStorage)